# printing out individuals for each concept in an ontology using rdflib

Tags: python, rdf, semantic-web, ontology, rdflib

I have and ontology written in OWL/RDF(using Protege). This ontology has been already populated with some individuals for each concept. I have ported it in to python using rdflib and FuXi packages. And I can successfully parse my Ontology and put in a graph. Now the only thing that I need to to do is that to print out all  individuals for each concept. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 4):

When you say all the individuals for each concept I guess that you mean `all the resources of rdf:type an specific class`. With `rdflib` you can easily do that by traversing the graph:

```
from rdflib import Graph
from rdflib import URIRef
g = Graph()
g.parse("ontology.owl")
aClass = URIRef("http://www.someuri.org/for/your/class")
rdftype = URIRef("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type")

for triple in g.triples((None,rdfType,aClass)):
    print triple
```

`(None,rdfType,aClass)` represents a constrain to iterate over the graph `g`. By setting
any of the three elements in the triple you constrain by any combination of subject,
predicate or object. In this case we only  constrain by predicate `rdftype` and
object `aClass`.

If you wanted all individuals members and all classes you could do:

```
for triple in g.triples((None,rdfType,None)):
    print triple
```

In which case we leave the object unbound to capture any OWL class.

Comment: @Hossein see the new version of the code. The code I posted before only works with the latest version of rdlib, this new version should work for you. Otherwise let me know what version of Python and rdflib you're running.